# Unity (5.4.1) networking: messages guaranteed to arrive?

Tags: unity, networking

In Unity (5.4.1). Are Commands, ClientRpcs and SyncVar calls/events guaranteed to arrive?
Or are they fire and forget (like UDP protocol)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All High Level API calls are guaranteed to arrive (With exceptions where clearly specified on the documentation). in UNet, there is an Unreliable channel and a Reliable channel.

Unity builds its own custom transport protocol ontop of the UDP protocol. Unity also allow you access the transport layer through Low Level API calls

Some resources:

- Low Level API : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetUsingTransport.html
- High Level API : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetUsingHLAPI.html
- Example of Unreliable messages :  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkClient.SendUnreliable.html